# Why am I getting a procedure entry point error for this simple C++ code?

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, sfml

I'm writing an SFML game and when I try to run the code this is the error I get:

> The procedure entry point `_gxx_personality_v0` could not be located in the dynamic link library `libstdc++-6.dll`

I've linked to all the libraries correctly and the include files are correct. I've even tried what other answers suggested by putting the `libstdc++-6.dll` inside the directory of my exectable but still nothing.

Another answer said to put the `MinGW/bin` directory before any other directory in the `PATH` environment variable, which I did as well and it still didn't work.

Note: I get this error only when I try to use SFML code. It runs successfully when I comment it out.

Comment: Is that a typo you made in `_gxx_perso*p*nality_v0`, or did it say so in the actual error?

Comment: Did you make sure that that the `libstdc++-6.dll` you copied all over the place is actually the correct one for the compiler you used? Often there are multiple `mingw-gcc`s installed, the one which comes with `MINGW`/`MSYS`, another separately installed never version, `cygwin`, `mingw-w64` compiler(s), each coming with their own version of `libstdc++-6.dll` which are not necessarily compatible...

Comment: @nmaier `libstdc++-6.dll` is located inside `MinGW/bin` folder as it always is. And my program runs fine only when I comment out SFML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the note you added tells me that the SFML stuff was compiled with another compiler version/configuration, newer one if memory serves right.

You need to make sure that `SFML` and your code are compiled by the same compiler (versions/configuration) or at least compatible compiler (versions/configuration).

I see that the latest binary packages of SFML use GCC 4.7, and the latest Code::Blocks (mingw) comes with the TDM GCC 4.7 build, so it might be enough to upgrade Code::Blocks and make sure you use the SFML GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) package (and use the gcc that comes with Code::Blocks, of course).

Otherwise, you should probably install the TDM-GCC 4.7 compiler build manually, or if nothing works, compile SFML yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a PATH ordering issue.

Most likely you'll have multiple libstdc++-6.dll files loaded in your path. You can check by running `where libstdc++-6.dll` in your command prompt.

What you do is to make sure your MinGW bin folder is loaded before everything else. Try moving it to the first one in your global PATH.

Comment: That was my case: I had the MinGW path in user's PATH, which is loaded after the global PATH. The `where` command is most useful, thank you for pointing it out.