# While trying to set up sfml 2.0 with code::blocks, the error "The procedure entry point __gx_personality_v0..."

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

"The procedure entry point __gx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll"

This error has been plaguing me for the past few days. I am following http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php

To try to get it to work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjF1J.png

Here is what the error message looks like. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a procedure entry point error for this simple C++ code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212090/why-am-i-getting-a-procedure-entry-point-error-for-this-simple-c-code)